# responsive SVG using viewbox

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, responsive, viewbox

I've managed to make a SVG responsive by using viewbox like this:

```
var svg = d3.select("#vis").append("svg") 
            .attr("width", "100%")
            .attr("height", "100%") 
            .attr("viewBox", "0 0 960 500")
            .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "none");
```

It's responsive and gets smaller as screen size gets smaller. The only problem is that the SVG is too big when loaded in maximum screen. Can I set a maximum size? So, it doesn't get too big once it reaches the maximum size even though screen is big.

Comment: Can you please create jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use CSS to give a max-width to the container?

```js
var svg = d3.select("#vis").append("svg")
  .attr("width", "100%")
  .attr("height", "100%")
  .attr("viewBox", "0 0 960 500")
  .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "none");
  
svg.append('circle')
  .attr('r', 100)
  .attr('cx', 300)
  .attr('cy', 300)
```

```css
#vis {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="vis"></div>
```

Comment: You can set the `max-width` directly on the `<svg>` element. Embeded in HTML it acts as a inline-box.